# homotopy type of the cone of a loop space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I read somewhere that for, a path connected CW complex $X$, there is a homotopy equivalence  of pairs between $(P_1X,\Omega X)$ and $(C\Omega X,\Omega X)$ where $P_1X$ denotes the set oh paths $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(1)=*$.
I need to learn more this fact, especially its proof. Any suggestions, comments, references, ... are welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

One has $$C\Omega X=I\times \Omega X \ \ / \ \{0\} \times \Omega X.$$
Map a point $(t,\gamma)$ in the cone to the restriction of $\gamma$ to $[0,t]$ (reparametrized).

This is a map of pairs $(C\Omega X,\Omega X)\to (P_1X,\Omega X)$, which is the identity on the subspace, and a homotopy equivalence $C\Omega X\to P_1X$, as both spaces are contractible.

Since everything has the homotopy type of a CW complex, it follows from the long exact sequence of homotopy groups that one has a homotopy equivalence of pairs.